# Внос данных через read_line в Rust

Tags: rust, best-practice

Подскажите пожалуйста, в  struct  можно вносить данные с помощью read_line? Просто стараюсь как-то попрактиковаться, создаю приложение которое будет брать данные который вводит пользователь, и выводить как таблицу своеобразную

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непосредственно - нет. ты получаешь данные из read_line, обрабатываешь ошибки, преобразуешь введённое значение к нужному типу с обработкой ошибок, а потом уже можешь присвоить полю структуры полученное значение.